# Mock static method called from constructor in java class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I want to mock the static method being invoked from the constructor of my class.

**My class:**

```
package com.javaeasily.demos.junit;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyClass {

private int number;
private static final ArrayList<String> ACTIVE_SERVICES_POST_RECONFIGURE = new ArrayList<>();

// Only allow construction if number is greater than one
MyClass() {
    ACTIVE_SERVICES_POST_RECONFIGURE.add("my-node-" + NodeUtils.getMyNode());
}

public void reconfigureNode() {
    if (ACTIVE_SERVICES_POST_RECONFIGURE.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
 }
}
```

Here NodeUtils.getMyNode() is the static method being invoked from the constructor of the class.

**NodeUtils.java Class:**

```
package com.javaeasily.demos.junit;

import org.apache.maven.surefire.shade.booter.org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
public class NodeUtils {
private static final String HOSTNAME_PREFIX = "my-node-";

public static String hostnameToNode(String hostname) {
    if (!hostname.startsWith(HOSTNAME_PREFIX)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(hostname + " is not recognized hostname");
    }
    return StringUtils.removeStart(hostname, HOSTNAME_PREFIX);
}

public static String getHostname() {
    return System.getenv("HOSTNAME");
}

public static String getMyNode() {
    return hostnameToNode(getHostname());
  }
}
```

MyClassTest.java

```
package com.javaeasily.demos.junit;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class MyClassTest {
private MyClass myclass;

@BeforeEach
public void SetUp() {
    myclass = new MyClass();
}

@Test
public void testReconfigureNode() {
    myclass.reconfigureNode();
 }
}
```

When I try & run the only test case I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.javaeasily.demos.junit.NodeUtils.hostnameToNode(NodeUtils.java:8)
at com.javaeasily.demos.junit.NodeUtils.getMyNode(NodeUtils.java:19)
at com.javaeasily.demos.junit.MyClass.<init>(MyClass.java:12)
at com.javaeasily.demos.junit.MyClassTest.SetUp(MyClassTest.java:11)
```

I am not sure how do we mock the method to avoid this error?

Since I am new to Java I am not able to catch this. Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: Your `NodeUtils` is assuming there's an environment variable called `HOSTNAME`.  It looks like there isn't, in your case, and that led indirectly to the `NullPointerException`.  I guess you should fix that so that if the environment variable isn't there, `NodeUtils` still does something sensible in `getMyNode`.

Comment: Also, this is not a JavaScript question, which is why I removed the tag.  Java and JavaScript are about as closely related as Ham and Hamburgers - at first glance, it looks like one might be contained in the other, but the closer you look, the more you'll be disappointed.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Thanks for your response. Are you suggesting I should set ENV variable HOSTNAME first in my unit test?

Comment: No, I'm saying you should fix your `NodeUtils` class so that it doesn't cause a `NullPointerException` when that variable is not set.

Comment: Well in real cases HOSTNAME ENV variable will never be null. Can we mock NodeUtils.getMyNode() to return something?

Comment: This sounds like a great reason to make `NodeUtils` nonstatic so you can pass a hostname in as a constructor argument instead of getting it from the system environment.  Modify your code to be more testable, don't try to mock things that really just aren't suited for mocking.

Comment: Or as per your suggestion, once I fix it. Post that if I want NodeUtils.getMyNode() to return some other value. How do we do that here?

Comment: @LouisWasserman But in my case hostname comes from the ENV variable only. Can we avoid NPE here?

Comment: I'm saying that you should change that by constructing NodeUtils with the env variable in production, and a custom value in tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to answer your question how to mock a static method: mockito allows this since version 3.8.0. You can find a tutorial [here at Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods)

This allows generating a statically mocked Object for a concrete context, which you can create within a try block. For your case this would look like the following.

**Fixed Unit Test**

```
package com.javaeasily.demos.junit;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.MockedStatic;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyClassTest {
    private MyClass myclass;

    @BeforeEach
    public void SetUp() {
        try (MockedStatic<NodeUtils> nodeUtilsMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(NodeUtils.class)) {
            nodeUtilsMockedStatic.when(NodeUtils::getMyNode).thenReturn("foo");
            myclass = new MyClass();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testReconfigureNode() {
            myclass.reconfigureNode();
    }
}
```

**Mockito dependency**

You need mockito with at least version 3.8.0 in your project.

With maven add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

With gradle add:

```
testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-inline', version: '3.8.0'
```

Comment: Just one question, myclass = new MyClass(); should be called from try block?

Comment: Yes, that's because nodeUtilsMockedStatic is a mock created only for the scope of the try block.